# how to remove List brackets in a csv file which was generated from a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv, dictionary, formatting

I am trying something similar-

```
sample={"name":["age","number","email"]}
#dictionary stores the relevant data in above format
with open('selected.csv','w') as csvf:
[csvf.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(key,value)) for key,value in 
sample.items()]

#writing data in a csv file with my formatting
"Aaron",[21,020303030,"Aaron@blahblah.com"]

#csv file sample entry
```

Everything works fine but CSV file shows List brackets, how can I remove them?

Comment: That is CSV. I have not included import CSV statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't difficult if you use the standard library [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

sample={"name":["age","number","email"]}
with open('selected.csv', 'w+', newline='') as csvf:
    writer = csv.writer(csvf)
    for k, v in sample.items():
        writer.writerow([k, *v])  # unpack v into a list with k
```

This would produce a file with one line:

```
name,age,number,email
```